# Monotouch, Monotouch.Dialog, the iPad and customization

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin.ios, controls

I'm in the process of developing an iPad-only survey-app using MonoTouch. With monotouch.dialog (mt.d) I found that building these interfaces can come quickly, which is awesome.

However... I also found that mt.d only does about 80% of what I want. Makes me wonder: should I invest in extending mt.d to my needs or should I choose something differently over mt.d?

Some of my requirements:

1. Radiogroups without transitions: I like the options to be
   presented right away (there's more than enough space on the iPad
   screen)
2. A rating UI control, such as
   http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dyrateview
3. Mixed radiogroups: like 3 predefined elements and a fourth which
   allows for manually added content

What are your thoughts on this? Can this be done easily (I'm a trained programmer, but quite new to both C# and iOS development)? Do you guys know of any online repositories of custom UI components with C#/MonoTouch bindings?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is of course a subjective opinion, but my take on it is that if you believe you can do your UI in UITableView (which MonoTouch.Dialog is based on), then you should go for MonoTouch.Dialog. If UITableView will not fit your needs, you should look for a different approach. MonoTouch.Dialog is quite flexible, and open-source, so if you need anything to be different you can just use the source code and modify it at will.